# Android typing animation in messaging app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-drawable, android-resources

I would like to implement a piece of Android UI that appears in a messaging app when the recipient is typing. Something like this, which appears in the Facebook Messenger Android app:

[image]

I imagine the solution is a combination of layout, drawable, and animation resource files, but I am stuck trying to pull all the components together into 1 piece of UI.

What is a high-level implementation of this Android UI?

(I can fine-tune the design and animation effect myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer here seems like a single high quality gif would be the answer. You could use this gradle dependency https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable which would allow you to get away with a single piece of layout instead of needing to worry about multiple nested views.